# Excel: 'AND' filter pivot table by value found in the same column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I need a pivot table to show how many times a combination occurs within the same ticket (column A).

Data is stored like this:

```
ticket  item
10001   1422
10001   2031
10002   1769
10002   2102
10002   2348
10003   1806
10004   1076
10004   1492
10004   1494
10004   1496
10004   2096
10004   2119
10004   2375
```

I would need Excel to show results like this:

```
item/item   1033    1036    1044    1051    1060    1095    1111    1113    1136    1139
1033    x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
1036    x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
1044    x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
1051    x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
1060    x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
1095    x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
1111    x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
1113    x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
1136    x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
1139    x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
```

Where "x" represents how many tickets were found that include both products. I believe that for Excel to do that, I would need to filter twice by "item", using an "AND" filter (not an OR).

I have tried everything, even adding the table to a model and then filtering from another table with the same items. Currently I can do this with formulas, but because of the time it takes to do it that way and the amount of different data sets I need to analyze, it is just not practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using **Power Query**. Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. It is available in **Excel 2010 Professional Plus and later versions**. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

Steps are:

1. Use **From Table** function under `Data` tab to Load your source table to the Power Query Editor;
2. Use **Merge Queries** function under `Transform` tab to merge the table with its own as set out below:

[image: Merging]

3. **Expand** the merged column (which is essentially a table) by clicking the button on the right hand side of the column header, and select `Item` only;

[image: Expanding]

4. **Close & Load** the new table to a new worksheet (by default), or you can change your `Query Options` to select `Specify custom default load settings` under `Data Load` so the new table will not be loaded physically but rather creating a connection of the query;
5. If you have loaded the table to a new worksheet, you can create a pivot table from it and put the two items column in the `Columns` and `Rows` field, and put the ticket column in the `Values` field but change the setting to show **Count** instead of **Sum** of tickets. If you've created a connection of the query instead, you can right click the connection in the `Workbook Queries` panel and choose to load it to the **Data Model** which I believe you are familiar with. Then you can create a pivot table using the table in the data model with the same settings. Then you should have something like the following:

[image: example]

> Each time you have updated the source table, make sure to **Refresh All Data** instead of refreshing the pivot table directly as you need to refresh the data table in the back end first especially in the case when you only created connection to the query and stored the table in the Data Model.

Here are the Power Query **M Codes** behind the scene for reference only. I only used built-in functions of the query editor which is simple and straight forward. Cheers :)

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Ticket", Int64.Type}, {"Item", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"Ticket"}, #"Changed Type", {"Ticket"}, "Changed Type", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Changed Type" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Changed Type", {"Item"}, {"Changed Type.Item"})
in
    #"Expanded Changed Type"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Terry W for taking the time to answer in such a clear and detailed way that is very easy to understand. It does work perfectly!